# Unable to setup replication in ClickHouse using Zookeeper

Tags: database, replication, clickhouse

I've spent past two days trying to setup replication in ClickHouse, but what ever configuration I try I end up with the same behavior.

I'm able to create a `ReplicatedMergeTree` table on the first node and insert data to it. Then I create a replica on the second node. The data gets replicated and I can see it querying the second node. But when I insert data to the second node the weird behavior starts. Data is not copied to the first node and it gets the following error:

```
2017.11.14 11:16:43.464565 [ 30 ] <Error> DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::queueTask()::<lambda(DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::LogEntryPtr&)>: Code: 33, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot read all data, e.what() = DB::Exception,
```

It is very similar to this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/508#issuecomment-284923966).

When I restart the first node it is able to load the new data inserted to the second node and seems to be working. However inserting some more data brings the same error again.

The most recent setup I tried:

Following the [tutorial](https://clickhouse.yandex/tutorial.html), I have a three node Zookeeper cluster with the following config:

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/opt/zoo2/data
clientPort=12181
server.1=10.201.1.4:2888:3888
server.2=0.0.0.0:12888:13888
server.3=10.201.1.4:22888:23888
```

The zookeeper config for ClickHouse loooks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
    <zookeeper>
        <node>
            <host>10.201.1.4</host>
            <port>2181</port>
        </node>
        <node>
            <host>10.201.1.4</host>
            <port>12181</port>
        </node>
        <node>
            <host>10.201.1.4</host>
            <port>22181</port>
        </node>
    </zookeeper>
</yandex>
```

I create all tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t_r (
  id UInt32,
  d Date
) ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/t_r', '03', d, (d, id), 8192);
```

The only difference accross all replicas is the replica id `'03'` which is set accordingly.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I figured out the issue by myself. Thanks to @egorlitvinenko I went through all the configs again and I noticed that for all three nodes I had set up the same `interserver_http_port`. It would not be problem if all the nodes were running on separate machines, but in my test scenario they run side by side hosted on the same OS.

Comment: Thx your comment helped me too :)

Comment: In my case all the nodes are running on a separate machines. Despite that I've got the same possible cause of error when try to create the database; Clickhouse cluster cannot update the Zookeeper tree.

`Code: 139. DB::Exception: Received from 127.0.0.1:9000. DB::Exception: There is no Zookeeper configuration in server config. (NO_ELEMENTS_IN_CONFIG)`

Answer (score 0):

> ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/t_r', '03', d, (d, id), 8192);

You should configure zookeeper unique id for each replicas. Currently you use '03', it is not correct.
In tutorial, by {replica} means macros, which configured in clickhouse config file on each nodes.

See - https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/table_engines/replication.html#replicatedmergetree

p.s. For futher help, please, provide config of all nodes.

Comment: When creating a `replicated` table I'm setting unique replica id for each ClickHouse server node. I use more or less default config for all three nodes, each node having a separate data, tmp, log, errlog directories.

Comment: As I can see, in your create statement there is only one id = '03'. Also 't_r' is id of node in zookeeper, and should be unique for shards. If you run different statements on different nodes, please, provide all.

Comment: The only difference in commands creating tables is the replica id which is set according to the node number. Because I'm using single shard regime the same 't_r' id is set on all nodes.

Comment: @TomášRepík it is quite interesting for me to help you and investigate this problem, with configurations it would be easier. I'm trying to reproduce it.